# BuildShip Gradle plugin on Eclipse, reports "syncrhonize gradle project workspace failed"

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, buildship

```
Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an unsupported configuration in the referenced Gradle build.
Project at '/home/jsiddharth/workspace/v2/mnoxwebservicesv2' can't be named 'mnoxwebserviceendpoints-..' because it's located directly under the workspace root. If such a project is renamed, Eclipse would move the container directory. To resolve this problem, move the project out of the workspace root or configure it to have the name 'mnoxwebservicesv2'.
org.eclipse.buildship.core.UnsupportedConfigurationException: Project at '/home/jsiddharth/workspace/v2/mnoxwebservicesv2' can't be named 'mnoxwebserviceendpoints-..' because it's located directly under the workspace root. If such a project is renamed, Eclipse would move the container directory. To resolve this problem, move the project out of the workspace root or configure it to have the name 'mnoxwebservicesv2'.
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultWorkspaceOperations.validateProjectName(DefaultWorkspaceOperations.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ProjectNameUpdater.checkProjectName(ProjectNameUpdater.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ProjectNameUpdater.ensureProjectNameIsFree(ProjectNameUpdater.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.addNewEclipseProjectToWorkspace(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeNonWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeGradleProjectWithWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.access$000(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation$1.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2225)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeProjectsWithWorkspace(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

My settings.gradle is

```
rootProject.name = 'mnoxwebserviceendpoints'

include '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:coregeneral',
    '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:databasepojos', 
    '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:backendcommons',
    '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:corehttpclient',
    '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:corehibernate', 
    '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:mnoxcache', 
    '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:coreemailservice',
    '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:coresmsservice', 
    '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:databasecrud', 
        '..:..:mnoxwebservicesv2:mnoxwebservicescommons',
    '..:..:mnoxbackendv2:operationserverendpoints'
```

My build.gradle has

```
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:coregeneral')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:databasepojos')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:backendcommons')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:corehttpclient')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:corehibernate')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:mnoxcache')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:coreemailservice')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:coresmsservice')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:databasecrud')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxwebservicesv2:mnoxwebservicescommons')
    compile project('..:..:mnoxbackendv2:operationserverendpoints')
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi projects are not supported by BuildShip plugin of eclipse. And they have no plans to include this support.

[Link](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/multibuild-projects-do-not-work-with-buildship/10595/5) to the blog post that confirms this

I will find out which plugin supports eclipse and update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed that the **"settings.gradle"** file was setting the root project name, and after the project rename, it still had the old name. Once I changed that name to the new name and refreshed the project, that error went away.

Actually this error is because of Eclipse,Ideallyeclips should refactor a whole project but it not refactoring settings.gradle file.

Comment: Are you saying that gradle on eclipse supports multiple project dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with your .project file generated by eclipse, delete the project from eclipse(not directory), reopen existing gradle project, rebuild it, issue will resolve.